# Comma as Decimal Separator in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to define the decimal separator for the numeric type float or double in elasticsearch to be a comma "," instead of the decimal point "."?

My use case is to parse some csv files with logstash's csv filter. However the numeric field in this file has comma as a decimal separator so instead of having for example an entry of **9.5** I have an entry of **9,5** which actually means "nine and a half". My mapping for this floating-point field looks as follows:
`"field_1" : {"type": "float", "index" : "analyzed" }`.

I could find a workaround to overcome this, which is by using logstash's mutate filter to convert the commas into points as follows: `gsub => ["field_1",",","."]`. However I would like to know whether it is in general possible to configure which character to be used as a decimal seperator for floating point fields in elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more details? Show an example that doesn't work and what you'd expect to get working.

Comment: I'm asking in a generic manner since I could find a work around for my use case through converting the commas to points with logstash's mutate filter. However I would like to know whether it is generally possible. I will edit the question to include more details though.

Comment: There we go, now we know you have logstash into the mix, can you briefly show what you've tried?

Comment: So I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. At least, I've never seen anything going in that sense.